# Thousands ip proxy TOR network

Tags: proxy, ip, tor

**I would like to know how to use TOR's thousands of ip's.**
I have heard some say that TOR has 22k-55k IPs, but I can not even use 1K per day
I have tried to set it up many different ways, turning it on / off etc ...
Any advice or information would help.

Comment: I've tried opening and closing it several times
I already tried this MaxCircuitDirtiness 10s

Answer (score 0):

You have already tried what I would suggest, so a few points:

- MaxCircuitDirtiness only effects the building of circuits, not the selection of endpoints ("exit nodes" i.e what your IP appears to be). As a simple example, you can take many routes to the Post Office but there are a limited number of Post Offices to choose from.
- Switching endpoints all the time is not very feasible from a technical standpoint, which is why the default for a new IP is 10 minutes.
- Math is against you. Even switching every minute (which is possible and gives perhaps about ~1440 addresses every 24 hours) probably eats up half that time in circuit building (so you're likely doing literally half of whatever you want to do). And to even get a true 1440 addresses for a single client assumes no duplicate connections in that 24 hours.
- This kind of quick rotation is likely less useful for most issues with anonymity. Tor fingerprinting typically relies on security leaks, correct correlation of seemingly trivial items and/or controlling a bunch of nodes (which your requests, regardless of IP, may be passing through).